# Creating an array of objects in Javascript that conform to a highly specific format

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I need to create an array of objects with a very specific format:

```
        var tags = [
            { key: "Cat In the Hat", value: 26 },
            { key: "One Fish Two Fish", value: 19 },
            { key: "Green Eggs and Ham", value: 18 }
                    ]
```

I have a two-dimensional array of keys (which are strings) and values (integers):

```
           books[0][0] = "Cat in the Hat";
           books[1][0] = 26;
           books[0][1] = "One Fish Two Fish";
           books[1][1] = 19;
           books[0][2] = "Green Eggs and Ham";
           books[1][2] = 18;
```

I've tried iterating over the books[] array to output each element as a string, which puts the entire element in quotes. I've tried writing to a new array with

```
'key : '+books[0][0]+', value: '+books[1][0];
```

but "key" and "value" get treated as strings and so put in quotes. I've tried mapping the array but I'm failing to get the syntax right:

```
    tags = books.map( function( key ) {
    return key.map( function( value ) { 
        return value.map( value ); 
    } );
} )
```

Which yields "value.map" is not a function. I know there's got to be a way to do this, I suspect array.map is the way, but the mechanics of how arrays and objects spit out data, the complexity of mapping a two dimensional array, and the specific formatting need for this is doing my head in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

> {
> key : books[0][0],
> value: books[1][0]
> }

Comment: This delivers only one entry: {  key: "Cat in the Hat",  value: 26 } but the OP wnts to create an array of objects.

Comment: You're right, Sascha, but I took the template and iterated it so: 

 for (i = 0; i < books[0].length; i++){
 tags[i] = { key : books[0][i], value: books[1][i] }

Answer (score 1):

You could use map over books[0] for the key and add the value of books[1] in the callback.

```js
function createTags(books) {
    let tags = books[0].map( function(key, i){
        return {"key": key, "value": books[1][i]}        
    }.bind(this));
    return tags;
}
        
let books = [0, 1];
books[0] = [];
books[1] = [];

books[0].push("Cat in the Hat");
books[1].push(26);

books[0].push("One Fish Two Fish");
books[1].push(19);

books[0].push("Green Eggs and Ham");
books[1].push(18);

console.log( createTags(books) );
```

Comment: Thanks Sascha, this answers my question about the syntax for mapping the array, so thanks for that, but it outputs "key" and "value" in double quotes, which renders the data useless to the piece of code I'm running it through.

Comment: I can't see the differences to the desired: `console.log(createTags(books)[1].key);` has the same result as `console.log(tags[1].key);`. In both cases the result is `"One Fish Two Fish"`.

Comment: Indeed, this works. When I run the code snippet the output shows "key" and "value" in quotes but as Nina points out below, that's apparently a formatting convention. When I insert the code into my javascript the array is generated in the same format I indicated I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could take a dynamic approach and get the result without hard coding of indices by using an array for the keys.

```js
const 
    books = [["Cat in the Hat", "One Fish Two Fish", "Green Eggs and Ham"], [26, 19, 18]],
    keys = ["key", "value"],
    result = books.reduce((r, a, i) => a.map((v, j) => ({ ...r[j], [keys[i]]: v })), []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I never would have thought of that one. But like the mapping suggestion from Sascha it outputs "key" and "value" in quotes.

Comment: it is just for format of the display. the keys itslfl of the objects is is without quotes.